# Make a bool parameter more readable

Tags: ruby

I want to avoid passing true as an argument to a method because it does not make sense to anybody who is reading the code for the first time:

e.g.

```
result = MyQuery.match "aa", user, true
```

You can see that it is passing a string to match on and a user but the true is anybody's guess.

How can I make this more explicit?

Comment: Is `match` our own method, or a gem you don't have control over?

Comment: RubyTapas has an episode about this specific issue a few weeks ago. Look for episode #119, Intention Revealing Arguments.  ( http://www.rubytapas.com/episodes )

Comment: In addition to the comment of Bala this might be an interesting article: http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/qt/opthash.htm

Answer (score 2):

A method should only do one thing. If it takes a boolean argument, it pretty much by definition does *two* things: one if the argument is true, another if the argument is false. (Either that, or the argument is useless.)

It is almost always better to provide two methods with sensible names.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `Hash` with a symbol that would be more meaningful.

```
result = MyQuery.match "bala", user, {alive: true}
```

In future, when the situation demands more options than true/false, it is easily achieved

```
result = MyQuery.match "bala", user, {alive: unlikely}
```

Comment: Note that if the hash is the last argument, the braces are optional, making this even nicer! `result = MyQuery.match "bala", user, alive: true`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constant variable for that boolean, giving it an helpful name:

```
MEANING_OF_TRUE = true
result = MyQuery.match "aa", user, MEANING_OF_TRUE
```

You can also explicitly comment the meaning of the `true` value:

```
result = MyQuery.match "aa", user, true # because ...
```

Finally you could also open `MyQuery` and define a constant inside:

```
class MyQuery
    MEANING_OF_TRUE = true
    MEANING_OF_FALSE = false
end
# ...
result = MyQuery.match "aa", user, MyQuery::MEANING_OF_TRUE
```

but you shouldn't really worry about that. If your API is well documented, a respectable programmer will have no problems in reading that line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explain what `true` means you can use a Symbol:

```
result = MyQuery.match "aa", user, :meaning_of_true
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, any of these might work, depending on the method:

```
OPTION = true
MyQuery.match "aa", user, OPTION

option = true
MyQuery.match "aa", user, option

MyQuery.match "aa", user, option = true

MyQuery.match "aa", user, :option

MyQuery.match "aa", user, option: true
```

Comment: Can you please fix your `"` and `'`?